# Raid - Software, Hardware, or none at all ( CENTOS )

Tags: centos, raid

I took over an old centos machine and I cannot figure out for the life of me if the server has a raid setup or not.

It has 2 Harddrives ( one of which is now red lighting on the bay ).

There are two 300GB drives in it.

df -h

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on 
/dev/mappe /VolGroup00-LogVol00
                      265G   49G  203G  20% / 
/dev/sda1             99M   19M   76M  20% /boot 
tmpfs                 4.0G     0  4.0G   0% /dev/shm
```

dmraid -s

```
no raid disks
```

I also tried using storcli

```
./storcli show all

Status Code = 0
Status = Success
Description = None

Number of Controllers = 0
```

I also have a backup server that has the identical output and no red lights on the drive bays.

any ideas?

thanks,

--E

Comment: Does it have a hardware RAID controller installed?

Comment: I cant reboot it so I am not sure.

Comment: How old is your version of CentOS that it doesn't even have `lspci`?

Comment: it does have lspci but when I run lspci -vv | grep -i raid .. i get no results

Comment: Try `dmesg | stor` and variations just in case. Also would the hosting provider know or be able to check?

Comment: `dmsetup table VolGroup00-LogVol00`

Comment: dmesg | grep -i stor shows no results

Comment: dmsetup table VolGroup00-LogVol00: 0 573440000 linear 8:2 384

Comment: could it be that I dont have any raid and the server is just ignoring that drive?